# Error: Attempt to assign property "name" on null

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am Working On a E-commerce Project with Laravel-8. I am facing a problem in editing the products og this E-commerce site. when I am clicking on 'Update' after editing the details of any product. It's Saying "Error
Attempt to assign property "name" on null"

Here's My Web.php code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\Homecomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Shopcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Cartcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Checkoutcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Detailscomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Categorycomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Headersearchcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\Searchcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\user\UserDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\AdminDashboardComponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\Admincategorycomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\Adminaddcategorycomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\Admineditcategorycomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\Adminproductcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\Adminaddproductcomponent;
use App\Http\Livewire\admin\Admineditproductcomponent;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Route::get('/', function () {
//   return view('welcome');
//});

Route::get('/',Homecomponent::class);

Route::get('/shop',Shopcomponent::class);

Route::get('/cart',Cartcomponent::class)->name('product.cart');

Route::get('/checkout',Checkoutcomponent::class);

Route::get('/product/{slug}',Detailscomponent::class)->name('product.details');

Route::get('/product-category/{category_slug}',categorycomponent::class)->name('product.category');

Route::get('/search',searchcomponent::class)->name('product.search');


//Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
//    return view('dashboard');
//})->name('dashboard');

//For User or Coustomer
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function(){
        Route::get('/user/dashboard',UserDashboardComponent::class)->name('user.dashboard');
});

//For Admin
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified','authadmin'])->group(function(){
        Route::get('/admin/dashboard',AdminDashboardComponent::class)->name('admin.dashboard');
        Route::get('/admin/categories',Admincategorycomponent::class)->name('admin.categories');
        Route::get('/admin/category/add',Adminaddcategorycomponent::class)->name('admin.addcategory');
        Route::get('/admin/category/edit/{category_slug}',Admineditcategorycomponent::class)->name('admin.editcategory');
        Route::get('/admin/products',Adminproductcomponent::class)->name('admin.products');
        Route::get('/admin/product/add',Adminaddproductcomponent::class)->name('admin.addproduct');
        Route::get('/admin/product/edit/{product_slug}',Admineditproductcomponent::class)->name('admin.editproduct');
});
```

Here's my editproductcomponent.php(class)  Code->

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Admineditproductcomponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $product_slug;
    public $product_id;
    public $name;
    public $slug;
    public $short_description;
    public $description;
    public $regular_price;
    public $sell_price;
    public $SKU;
    public $stock_status;
    public $featured;
    public $quantity;
    public $image;
    public $category_id;
    public $newimage;

    public function mount($product_slug)
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug',$product_slug)->first();

        $this->name = $product->name;
        $this->slug = $product->slug;
        $this->short_description = $product->short_description;
        $this->description = $product->description;
        $this->regular_price = $product->regular_price;
        $this->sell_price = $product->sell_price;
        $this->SKU = $product->SKU;
        $this->stock_status = $product->stock_status;
        $this->featured = $product->featured;
        $this->quantity = $product->quantity;
        $this->image = $product->image;
        $this->category_id = $product->category_id;
        $this->product_id = $product->product_id;

    }

    public function generateSlug()
    {
        $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name,'-');
    }

    public function updateproduct()
    {
        $product = Product::find($this->product_id);
        $product->name = $this->name;
        $product->slug = $this->slug;
        $product->short_description = $this->short_description;
        $product->description = $this->description;
        $product->regular_price = $this->regular_price;
        $product->sell_price = $this->sell_price;
        $product->SKU = $this->SKU;
        $product->stock_status = $this->stock_status;
        $product->featured = $this->featured;
        $product->quantity = $this->quantity;
        if($this->newimage)
        {
            $imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp. '.' . $this->newimage->extension();
            $this->newimage->storeAs('products',$imageName);
            $product->image = $imageName;
        }
        $product->category_id = $this->category_id;
        $product->save();
        session()->flash('message','Product has been Updated Successfully');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.admineditproductcomponent',['categories' => $categories])->layout('layouts.base');
    }
}
```

Here's my editproductcomponent.blade.php(View)  Code->

```
<div>
    <div class="container"style="padding:30px 0;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                Edit Product
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a href="{{route('admin.products')}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">All Products</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" wire:submit.prevent="updateproduct">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="name" wire:keyup="generateSlug">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Slug</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Product Slug" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="slug">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Short Description" class="form-control" wire:model="short_description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" wire:model="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Regular Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Regular Price" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="regular_price">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Sell Price</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Sell Price" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="sell_price">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">SKU</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="SKU" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="SKU">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Stock</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control" wire:model="stock_status">
                                        <option value="instock">InStock</option>
                                        <option value="outofstock">Out of Stock</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Featured</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control" wire:model="featured">
                                        <option value="0">No</option>
                                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control input-md" wire:model="quantity">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Product Image</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="file" class="input-file" wire:model="newimage">
                                    @if($newimage)
                                        <img src="{{$newimage->temporaryUrl()}}" width="120">
                                    @else
                                        <img src="{{asset('assets/images/products')}}/{{$image}}" width="120" alt="">
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label">Category</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select name="" id="" class="form-control" wire:model="category_id">
                                        <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                            <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    @if(Session::has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                    @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                                                                      
    </div>
</div>
```

Please Help Me....

Answer (score 1):

remove this line at mount(($product_slug))
$this->product_id = $product->product_id;

and write the following line

$this->product_id = $product->id;

Because column product_id is not exist in database product table

Answer (score 1):

just change **`product_id`** to **`id`** in editproductcomponent.php

I think you don't have `product_id` in your products table, but of course, each product has an `id`.

[editproductcomponent.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrT2D.png)

I just tried it and it works

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what's happening is the product isn't found in the database, so `$product` ends up being `null`.  Then you're attempting to set a value for `$product->name`.

Your route/controller structure is a little unconventional.  I'd recommend referencing Laravel's [Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers) documentation for how to implement a standard CRUD controller, and leverage automatic model binding so you can avoid this lookup altogether.

However, sticking with this what you can do is first check to ensure that `$product` is not null before attempting to access object properties like:

```php
if($product = Product::where('slug', $product_slug)->first()) {
    $product->name = $this->name;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: yes sir, I have ensured  that my $product is not null and also I can make a new product by using  $product but at the time of Editing it's not working 

Comment: According to the error `$product` is definitely `null` when attempting to set the `name` property 

Comment: thank you so much sir after a long time I actually noticed that my $product is null...i solved it....Thank u sir

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Product::find($this->product_id);
```

result $product is empty
Check with a condition that it is not empty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).